# PostgreSQL: password authentification failed on macOS(Mojave)

Tags: postgresql, macos

I just installed postgres through Terminal and when I try to createdb "test" I allways get this error:

createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user ""

I know there are a few threads already on this topic but nothing works. Most suggestions were to update "pg_hba.conf" but I'm doing it wrong or there is something else... I also tried to remove the postgres password but it doesn't work... nothing seems to work...

[image]

Comment: It is odd that createdb says '... for user ""'. What if you give it an explicit -U flag?

Comment: it said: '...for user "my-username" ', but SO removed that, and left it like an empty string...

Comment: Heh, that's "helpful" of SO. :) How did you install Postgres, more excactly? Have you created a Postgres user with the name that createdb is trying to use (which, I suppose, is the same as your Unix login name)?

Comment: I installed Postgres with brew but it didn't ask at any point for a password and the default user was "root"(I tried with my user as well...). 
I gave up on it and started with MySQL which asked for a password and a user(and I set them up). I was able to use it from the Terminal to create db and do queries and I connected to a server(localhost). It responded with something but now this one's asking for a password too(which doesn't mach what I set up)... 
Now they're both hanging there treating me like a stranger...